# Sublime XDebug , PHP

Tags: php, sublimetext3, xdebug

I installed XDebug client using the package control in sublime text 3.
I have XAMPP installed on my MAC. My Document Root in the /xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf points to the actual PHP project root directory e.g. DocumentRoot "/Users/johndoe/myproj". I saved the project and put the following as well:

```
{
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "."
    }
],
"settings":
{
    "xdebug":
    {
        "debug": true,
        "url": "127.0.0.1/app/index.html#/home"
    }
}
```

}

However I do not see the debug working. (a) I am unable to pull a browser when I do a Tools->XDebug->Start Debugging (Launch Browser).

Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong ? Please suggest given the current Document Root Set as mentioned above